# (Rails) asset from asset pipeline shows up in index.html.erb file, but not show.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to get both an image and a CSS style from my asset pipeline ni rails 4. I have an index.html.erb and a show.html.erb. I have the exact same code in each, but it works in the index.html file, but not in the show.html file.

Code:

```
 <!-- Styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles-bluegreen.css" id="theme-styles">

 <a href="index.html" id="logo">
     <img src="assets/my-logo.png" alt="My Blog">
 </a>
```

I have this exact same code, because I copied and pasted (yes, I know it's against rails dry policy). I originally had this in a _header.html.erb partial, and the code did not work in the partial either, so i put the exact code in each file, and it works in the index.thml.erb, but no in the show.html.erb. What could be the reason?

Note, I have also tried:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/styles-bluegreen.css" id="theme-styles">
```

and

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/stylesheets/styles-bluegreen.css" id="theme-styles">
```

Here is my asset pipeline:

[image: asset pipeline]

Comment: Is there a reason for you not to use `stylesheet_link_tag`?

Comment: not to sound like a total idiot...but I'm not sure what that is, I'm very new to rails and web development. I will look into it though, thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you copy-paste the snippet, there's no reason for them to behave differently except one of your view (index or show) is cached and it is served to the client directly instead of being rendered. Can you check if this is the case?

Btw, you really should use `stylesheet_link_tag` because links to assets might differ from `development` to `production` environments. This helper renders those links correspondingly to environments.

Comment: I will look into the stylesheet_link_tag thing. I'm very new to rails and am not sure what that is, I will look into it though. I'm also not sure if the views are or are not being cached, I will also try to search some and see what I can find about that.

Comment: You don't need to feel bad nor tell people that you are new to Rails as long as you are willing to learn. If you can post to the question the link for us to see the whole application structure, it would be easier to address what's wrong.

Comment: there is a reason why it would work on index and not show. it's because of relative paths since show page usually is one level deeper and will not find the relative path. but using asset_path like Dan12-16 said should work

Answer (score 0):

isn't it `href="<%= asset_path('styles-bluegreen.css')%>"`

And then for the picture `src="<%= asset_path('my-logo.png')%>"`

Also, you'd have to add .erb to the end of the show.html filename (so show.html.erb)

That usually works for me.